# How to add multiple base path mappings from different projects into the same AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, amazon-route53

We have separate AWS CDK projects for different APIs. We want to use same subdomain with different base path mappings for the same API Gateway resource. For example; lets say we have two APIs which are `tenantApi` and `invoiceApi` mapping to `test.example.com/tenant` and `test.example.com/invoice`. This is doable from one repository with creating one RestApi and defining multiple base path mappings to it. However, I couldn't find a way to achieve this doing it from different repositories since I need to create only one ARecord for the subdomain. My thought was creating `ARecord` inside a repository where we manage shared resources and importing that record from the repositories we will use the same Api Gateway.

Here is the simple aws cdk code about how I am creating an Api Gateway. As you can see, we have to pass RestApi instance into `route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias` so I am not really sure if we can create a ARecord before creating an Api Gateway.

```
export class ApiGatewayStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StackEnvProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const tenantApi = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'tenantApi', {
      domainName: {
        domainName: props.context['domainName'],
        certificate: acm.Certificate.fromCertificateArn(this, 'certificateArn', props.context['certificateArn']),
        basePath: 'tenant'
      },
      deploy: true,
      deployOptions: {
        stageName: 'prod',
      },
      defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
        allowMethods: apigateway.Cors.ALL_METHODS,
        allowOrigins: apigateway.Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
      }
    });

    const zone = route53.HostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'Zone', { domainName: 'example.com' });

    // create an alias for mapping
    new route53.ARecord(this, 'domainAliasRecord', {
      zone: zone,
      recordName: "test",
      target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new ApiGateway(tenantApi)),
    });

    const methodOptions: apigateway.MethodOptions = {
      methodResponses: [
        {
          statusCode: '200',
          responseParameters: {
            'method.response.header.Content-Type': true,
          },
        },
        {
          statusCode: '400',
          responseParameters: {
            'method.response.header.Content-Type': true,
          },
        },
      ],
    };

    const postPaymentsLambda = new NodejsFunction(this, 'postTenantLambda', {
      entry: './lambda/rest/tenant-api/post-tenant-api.ts',
      handler: 'handler',
      memorySize: 512,
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
    });

    // tenant/v1
    const tenantV1 = tenantApi.root.addResource('v1');
    tenantV1.addMethod('POST', new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(postPaymentsLambda), methodOptions);

  }
}
```

I appreciate for any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to first create a `domainName` then create an `ARecord` with targeting that `domainName` which can be imported from different APIs I want to attach.

```
// create domain name for api gateway
const domainName = new apigateway.DomainName(this, 'domainName', {
  domainName: `test.${props.domainName}`,
  certificate: acm.Certificate.fromCertificateArn(this, 'certificateArn', props.certificateArn),
  endpointType: apigateway.EndpointType.REGIONAL,
  securityPolicy: apigateway.SecurityPolicy.TLS_1_2,
});

const zone = route53.HostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'hostedZone', {
  domainName: props.context['domainName']
});

// create an alias for mapping
new route53.ARecord(this, 'apiGatewayDomainAliasRecord', {
  zone: zone,
  recordName: 'test',
  target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new r53target.ApiGatewayDomain(domainName)),
});

new CfnOutput(this, 'apiGatewayDomainNameAliasTarget', {
  value: domainName.domainNameAliasDomainName,
  description: 'domainNameAliasTarget attribute used when importing domain name',
  exportName: 'apiGatewayDomainNameAliasTarget'
});
```

Later on, I will import this `domainName` to create a `BasePathMapping`. There are three attributes used when importing a domainName;

- **domainName**: the domainName we created before.
- **domainNameAliasHostedZoneId**: Hosted ZoneId where the domain is defined.
- **domainNameAliasTarget**: AWS documentation doesn't clearly state out about what it is. Basically, it is the `domainNameAliasDomainName` value of the `domainName` we created at the very first place.

```
const tenantApi = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'tenantApi', {
  deployOptions: {
    stageName: 'dev',
  },
  deploy: true,
  defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
    allowMethods: apigateway.Cors.ALL_METHODS,
    allowOrigins: apigateway.Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
  }
});

const domainName = apigateway.DomainName.fromDomainNameAttributes(this, 'domainName', {
  domainName: `test.${props.domainName}`,
  domainNameAliasHostedZoneId: props.hostedZoneId,
  domainNameAliasTarget: Fn.importValue(props.apiGatewayDomainNameAliasTarget),
});

const nodeBasePathMapping = new apigateway.BasePathMapping(this, 'nodeBasePathMapping', {
  basePath: 'node',
  domainName,
  restApi: tenantApi,
});
```